# Displaying only merge commits and commits that are not on the merged branches

Tags: git

We have used to generate a change log based on `git log --merges`. This worked fine, as the merge commit message contained issue number and a short description.

Now we have started squashing smaller commits without any merge commit. That breaks our changelog workflow.

Is there any way I can get all the merge commits *and* the single commits on my `master` branch that are not in any other feature branch?

Comment: Does [git show-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch) do what you want?

Comment: @Andy Not at all. It shows everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "git log --first-parent" is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow makes sure that the first parent of each commit in the relevant branch is the previous version of that branch, you might want to try `git log --first-parent`.

### What is the "first parent"?

Each commit has one (for "single commits" as you called it) or more (merge commits) parents. In case of merges these parents have an order, where the first parent is the target for the merge (doing `git merge feature-a` in master leaves the old HEAD of master as the first parent, while the HEAD of feature-a becomes the second parent of the new commit). The option `--first-parent` only follows the first parents of all commits. So this should give you all merges into the current branch and all commits into it.

### How could this fail?

A common case in which this does not work is if someone does a `git pull` creating a commit to merge remote changes into his local branch (i.e. not fast-forwarding). In this case the first parent would be the previous local version, removing all merges to your master branch from `git log --first-parent` which were not part of the local master before. This will create a history like this:

```
* Merge branch 'master' of your-remote into master
|\
| * Previous version of remote master
| |
* | Local change
| |
|/
* Last common commit
```

Where the first parent of the top merge is the "Local change" and `git log --first-parent` will only show the top merge, "Local change" and "Last common commit".

### When will this work?

`git log --first-parent` will work good for your case if there is one central repository which is used to merge all required changes. This might be one maintainer who pulls changes from other repositories and makes sure that this never results in fast-forwards (e.g. by using "git pull/merge --no-ff"). Or you are using a tool for pull requests like Atlassians Stash or Github and only merging to master via those pull requests.

You can read more about the usage of `--first-parent` in [this blog post](https://git-blame.blogspot.de/2012/03/fun-with-first-parent.html) by Junio C Hamano, the maintainer of git.